# React-Native call a function on default animation end?

Tags: android, ios, animation, react-native

In my App screen, I am calling several API's on `componentDidMount()` as shown below

```
componentDidMount(){
      approverName = I18n.t('setApprover',{locale:locale});
      AsyncStorage.getItem("authKey").then((ak) => {
          authKey = ak;
          setTimeout(() => {currentContext.props.getleavetypes(ak)}, 10000);
          setTimeout(() => {currentContext.props.getCategory(ak)}, 10000);
          setTimeout(() => {currentContext.props.getProjects(ak)}, 10000);
        }).done();

    }
```

Since API calls occur parallelly to animation there is a delay during screen loading(animation too slow), I tried calling API after a certain timeout this is not helping.

Please tell me how to call the below functions

```
currentContext.props.getleavetypes(ak)
currentContext.props.getCategory(ak)
currentContext.props.getProjects(ak)
```

on animation end.I have imported nothing related to animation and there is no code related to it.its the default animation in react-native.